# Count the group of shapes in powerpoint without using .type property

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2010, powerpoint-2013

The script which I have tested is running from excel application, which will count the shapes of pictures and count of actual shapes (that is textbox,placeholder) .Below is the script which pops up messages with the count of pictures and shapes

```
Sub countshapes()
Dim strname As String
Dim thisslide As Long
Dim strshape() As String

-----Count the number of slides in presentation 

For thisslide = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides.count

With ActivePresentation.Slides(thisslide)
ReDim strshape(0 To 0)

For Each oshp In .Shapes

If InStr(1, oshp.Name, "Picture") > 0 Then
ReDim Preserve strshape(0 To a)
strshape(a) = oshp.Name
a = a + 1

Else

ReDim Preserve strshape(0 To d)
strshape(d) = oshp.Name
d = d + 1
End If

Next oshp
End With
Next
MsgBox a
MsgBox d
```

The count of shapes and pictures are displayed perfectly 
But am unable to get the count of group of shapes, this can be easily achieved by .type=msogroup property however that property will not help me in some of the presentations which have many grouped shapes.

Please help me to update the script by using name of the shapes likewise the above script

Comment: How about using `TypeOf`... look at this: [Check whether shape is a group](https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/check-whether-shape-is-a-group.2745324/)

Comment: @PeterT thank you for the link am unable to get **typeof** property to count the shapes of  powerpoint presentation from excel vba application.I tried the below code but it throwed an error this member can only be access in group when shp = groupi                   'Sub test10()

Dim shp As Shape
Dim sld As Slide
Dim i As Variant
Dim grps As Object

For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
For Each shp In sld.Shapes
Set grps = shp.GroupItems
If grps Is Nothing Then
Debug.Print shp.Name
Else
For Each grp In grps
Debug.Print grp.Name
Next grp
End If
Next shp
Next sld
End Sub`

Comment: It's difficult to get a firm handle on the problem without understanding exactly what's in the PowerPoint. If you can upload or post an example slide deck to illustrate the problem it would help.

Comment: @Peter thanks for your reply have researched and got some idea how to do it will post it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've mentioned in your question that you don't want to use the .Type property w/o explaining the reason for this. Since it gives you a direct way to do what you need, I'll mention that you can test the .Type of each oShp and if it's msoGroup, oShp.GroupItems.Count will give you the number of shapes in the group. For example, you could pass each shape to this function and sum the results as you go:

```
Function CountGroupShapes(oSh As Shape) As Long
    If oSh.Type = msoGroup Then
        CountGroupShapes = oSh.GroupItems.Count
    Else
        CountGroupShapes = 1
    End If
End Function
```

Bear in mind that this won't give accurate results if there are going to be groups within groups.